# How to script automatic actions on web?

Tags: scripting, automation

Its a very general question:) For example I want to be able to automatically check if a page was updated, or to make some daily action online... Where would I start with that? Which languages/programs could be used?

Answer (score 1):

I use this tools too. I like Geb! But you can try Java + Selenium.
You choice depends on the task you need to do and understand the approach the tool for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this awesome Groovy library - [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/).